# Unable to resize instance of symbol in Sketch 3.7

Tags: sketch-3

In Sketch 3.7 when I convert an artboard into a symbol and then insert that symbol into another artboard, I can no longer resize that symbol (the resize handles and the width/height fields in the right menu are disabled). The only way to enlarge the symbol on the artboard is by changing the size of the symbol itself which impacts the other instances of the symbol.

How can I enlarge an instance of a symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer my own question. It's not possible. Symbols can't be resized in Sketch 3.7.